# WindowsMediaPlayer in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to use a WindowsMediaPlayer in my Delphi Project with Delphi 7. I want to use some videos with this Windowsmediaplayer. I've got an openDialog and time to time I call the video files to open. But Windowsmediaplayer some times runs as fullscreen sometimes runs in a small rect (not full screen). I want it runs fullscreen in a Panel. So far I couldn't achieve it.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: -1 You still won't give us any clues as to what you are talking about, show code etc. And your response to the answer you have received makes no sense. You must try harder if you want help. You can't expect us to read your mind and somehow magic details out of thin air. In order to get help you are going to have to invest time to write a proper question that can be answered. -1

Comment: I must agree on David here. Without more information we can't help you more. Even my existing aswer was more just a gues based on my expirience with similar problem. What we would need is more information of did you set up your component (what properties did you use) and more information about the video itself you are trying to play (with which codec has it been made, what is the default video resolution etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play videos using TMediaPlayer component you first have to set its Display property to some windowed controll like form or panel.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.Display

This will render video output on the selected control. By default video will be streched to the controll size which is what you want.

But if the video aspect ratio isn't the same as the aspect ratio of the controll on which you are rendering then the video will get distorted. To overcome that TMediaPlayer has another propery called DisplayRect using which you can force the video to be rendered in desired rectangle inside the controll you are rendering on. By using this you can get those balck stripes that most modern media players make when video aspect ratio isn't the same as your screens aspect ratio.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.MPlayer.TMediaPlayer.DisplayRect

Comment: I see what you mean but I use